# Is there a way to get faster dependent dropdowns?

Tags: ajax, forms

I have a **complex node** form with a series of dependent dropdowns (pick option a, update choices for option b, pick b, update choices for option c, etc.).  It's all working fine with the standard **ajax** framework built into the Drupal form API.  But it's really, really slow - every ajax call causes every form field to be validated, the (complex) **form_alter** function is called twice, etc.

Is there a better way to decrease load time?

In my particular case, I don't need all of the overhead.  It's really easy to write a simple, speedy callback to validate selection a and generate the new set of options for b, and easy to update b on the form using normal, **non-FAPI ajax**.  But when the form is submitted, the selection for b does not validate (since the form knows nothing about the new set of options).  Is there a way to overcome that hurdle and feed the new options into the form without going through the **FAPI ajax workflow**?

Note that this is NOT a custom form, but is a node form being customized through a **hook_form_alter** .